# Optimize C for-loop performance with openmp

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested, openmp

I have a simple `for`-loop that calculates an `array[n]` depending on the 
corresponding row at an array `X[n][d]`.

```
array *function(X, n, d){
    double *array = calloc(n,sizeof(double));
    //#pragma omp parallel
    {
        //#pragma omp parallel for if(n>15000)
        for( i=0 ; i<n-1; i++)
        {
            //#pragma omp parallel for shared(X,j, i) reduction(+: sum)
            //#pragma omp parallel for if(d>100) reduction(+:distances[:n]) private(j)
            for ( j=0; j< d; j++)
            {
                array[i] += (pow(X[(j+1)*n-1]-X[j*n+i], 2));
            }
            array[i] = sqrt(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Consider `n` to be as high as `n=100000` and `d` can have a predefined value from `d=2` to `d=100`. The `function()` is called multiple times (`2^k`) at each `k`th iteration. So the pattern is: at the first iteration it is called once, at the second iteration it is called twice, at the third iteration it is called four times etc...Also `n` diminishes by one in every iteration (`n-=1`).

I have tried different combinations of the `openmp` directives that I have put as comments in the sample code but no matter what I have tried, the code performs equally or better without the `openmp` directives.

What are some good ways/techniques to improve the time performance of the above loop using `openmp`?

Comment: Have you checked at the non-openmp (but optimized) generated code? Compilers these days are pretty good at optimizations and that might count for some of the difference. Another thing that might be relevant is caches and cache coherency between threads when using OpenMP.

Comment: I am compiling with the `-O3` optimization flag. How could I check the optimized code though? The only thing I know is the sequential part that I have written by hand.

Comment: Why are you squaring a value and then taking its square root? `√(x²)` is `x`...

Comment: @Shawn That was a typo. I apologize

Comment: You're sure of your code now? What is `distances` and how does it link with `array`?

Comment: It is the same variable-array. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell without something to test it, but I would try something like this:

```
double* function( double* X, int n, int d ) {
    double *array = malloc( n * sizeof( double ) );
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule( static )
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n - 1; i++ ) {
        double sum = 0;
        for( int j = 0; j < d; j++ ) {
           double dist = X[( j + 1 ) * n - 1] - X[j * n + i];
           sum += dist * dist;
        }
        array[i] = sqrt( sum );
    }
    return array;
}
```

I'm not sure it will be any more effective than your code, but it has a few improvements which should have an impact in performance:

1. To avoid initializing the array to 0 in the sequential part and also allow for hopefully better optimization from the compiler, I replaced the `calloc()` by a plain `malloc()` and used a local variable `sum` for accumulating the partial sums.
2. I've put the parallelization pragma as outermost as I could to maximize parallelism.
3. I've used a local `dist` variable to store the temporary distance between the 2 current values of `X`, and just multiplied it by itself, avoiding a costly call to the much more complex `pow()` function.

Now, depending on the result you get from that, you could consider adding the same sort of `if( n > NMIN )` statement as you had initially on the `#pragma omp parallel for` directive. The value for this `NMIN` would be for you to determine according to your measured performance.
Another possible direction for optimization would be to place the `parallel` directive outside of the function. That would spare you numerous thread starts/stops. However, you'd have to add a `#pragma omp single` before the call to `malloc()` and remove the `parallel` from the existing directive.

Comment: Thank you. That has added some good improvement. Moreover, do you think that by adding `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:sum)` before the second loop could improve the performance, more (for big `d` say like `d=100`)? I 've tried adding it but unfortunately I get a huge stall and I don't understand why. Also could you explain why those improvements you 've suggested, enhanced the performance of the code?

Comment: "do you think that by adding #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:sum) before the second loop could improve the performance". Since you say that  "n" is large enough (>10x number of cores), you will already have enough parallelism to exploit all of your cores so there is no point in adding nested parallelism by also trying to parallelise the inner loop).